# Solving Secondary Linear ODE : $xy''+y'-xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE is$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}-xy=0$$
I thought that this equation looks very similar with Bessel's equation
so I tried substitution $t=ix$.

Then by $\frac{dy}{dx}=i\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$,

ODE becomes $$ity''+iy'+ity=0$$

This is Bessel's Equation so the solution will be $y=c_1J_0(t)+c_2Y_0(t)=c_1J_0(ix)+c_2Y_0(ix)$.

But Wolframalpha told me the exact solution is $y=c_1J_0(ix)+c_2Y_0(-ix)$.

Could you tell me where I am wrong??

Thank you.

Comment: What is $t$? You didn't define the variable $t$

Comment: @KimPeek $t=ix$

Comment: I wrote I tried substitution $x$ by $t=ix$.

Comment: Whoops sorry, my head is somewhere else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $Y_0(i x)$ in terms of the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kinds $I_0$ resp $K_0$, as
\begin{equation}
 Y_0(i x) = -\frac{2}{\pi}\left[I_0(x)(\log x - \log i x) + K_0(x)\right],
\end{equation}
see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselY/16/01/01/0004/). Similarly, we can write $J_0(i x)$ as
\begin{equation}
 J_0(i x) = I_0(x),
\end{equation}
see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/16/01/01/0002/). Therefore,
\begin{equation}
 c_1 J_0(i x) + c_2 Y_0(i x) = -\frac{2}{\pi} c_2 K_0(x) + \left[c_1 - c_2\frac{2}{\pi}(\log x - \log i x)\right] I_0(x).\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now, $\log (-i x) = - \text{sgn}(x)\pi + \log i x$ using the standard log branch cut, so
\begin{align}
 c_1 J_0(i x) + c_2 Y_0(-i x) &= -\frac{2}{\pi} c_2 K_0(x) + \left[c_1 - c_2\frac{2}{\pi}(\log x - \log i x + \text{sgn}(x)\pi)\right] I_0(x)\\
&= -\frac{2}{\pi} c_2 K_0(x) + \left[\left(c_1 - 2\, \text{sgn}(x)c_2\right) - c_2\frac{2}{\pi}(\log x - \log i x)\right] I_0(x),
\end{align}
which is equivalent to $(1)$ under the redefinition of the free constant
\begin{equation}
 c_1 \to c_1 - 2\, \text{sgn}(x)c_2.
\end{equation}

Comment: Wow very cool thank you!